# openbsd: why quirks-1.87 was installed all of a sudden?

Tags: package-management, openbsd

I was trying to install mysql on OpenBSD; instead, somehow quirks-1.87 was installed, whereas mysql was claimed to not be found.  Why?

```
opti# setenv PKG_PATH ftp://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/`uname -r`/packages/`machine -a`/
opti# pkg_add mysql
Can't find mysql
opti# pkg_add -ri mysql
quirks-1.87: ok
Can't find mysql
opti# pkg_add -ri mysql
Can't find mysql
opti#
```

```
opti# uname -rms
OpenBSD 5.4 amd64
```

Answer (score 5):

The quirks package is an OpenBSD maintained package for "exceptions to pkg_add rules" it is used internally by the package tools, and so is installed the first time you install a package.  MySQL was not found, because there is no package called `mysql`.  You are probably looking for `mysql-server` and/or `mysql-client`.

For information on finding packages, see the official OpenBSD FAQ: http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html#PkgFind